# Split File into chunks keeping complete lines in solaris

Tags: perl, shell, awk, solaris, solaris-10

How can I split a file into 3 with equal (or almost equal) number of lines without breaking a line. 
for example split a file of 25 lines into 3 files of 9,8 and 8 lines each.
I know of `split -n l/3` but does not work on Solaris10.
Tried some stuff i got online but did not give desired result like:

```
!/usr/bin/ksh
fspec=~/input.list
num_files=3
total_lines=$(wc -l <${fspec})
((lines_per_file = (total_lines + num_files - 1) / num_files))
split -l ${lines_per_file} ${fspec} files.
```

Comment: Please show what you have tried and explain the problem you are having

Comment: @Jotne: If that is the full extent of what he has tried then he doesn't deserve any help

Comment: @Borodin, Tried some stuff i got online but did not give desired result like: `#!/usr/bin/ksh
fspec=~/input.list
num_files=3
total_lines=$(wc -l <${fspec})
((lines_per_file = (total_lines + num_files - 1) / num_files))
split -l ${lines_per_file} ${fspec} files.
`

Comment: @user3437245: Please add information like that by editing your question. And rather than searching everywhere for a ready-made solution to your problem, especially a Korn shell solution, wouldn't it interest you to think of one for yourself? Do you know any programming languages at all? So far it really sounds like you're just in the wrong job.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Here is a generic solution for you in `awk`

```
awk '{a[NR]=$0}  END {t=int (NR/s);r=((NR/s-t)*s);while (n<s) for (i=t*n+++1;i<=t*n;i++) print a[i] > "file"n;while (i++<=NR) print a[i-1] > "file"n}' s=3 infile
```

This splits the `infile` to `s` numbers of file.  If you set `s=3` you get `file1` `file2` `file3`
The data that does not divide up, ends up in last file.

---

Example

```
cat number
1       one
2       two
3       three
4       four
5       five
6       six
7       seven
8       eight
9       nine
10      ten
```

```
awk '{a[NR]=$0}  END {t=int (NR/s);r=((NR/s-t)*s);while (n<s) for (i=t*n+++1;i<=t*n;i++) print a[i] > "file"n;while (i++<=NR) print a[i-1] > "file"n}' s=3 number
```

```
cat file1
1       one
2       two
3       three
```

```
cat file2
4       four
5       five
6       six
```

```
cat file3
7       seven
8       eight
9       nine
10      ten
```